# Passing value to anonymous function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just updated the code and below is the full version of the code

If `data` returns `0` I want to get the text value of the selected option and append it to a div. Now data returns `0` and the div with class `iconSuccess` shows up but the value of `$a` cannot be gotten. I try to `alert($a)` or even `alert(1)` in the `if` condition statement but nothing happens. I need to get the value of `$a` in the `if` condition statement. How can I pass the value to the function that return data?

below is the full version of the code

```
 $('#categoryList').change(function () {
        $a = $("#categoryList option:selected").text();
        $( ".iconSuccess" ).hide();
        $("#categoryList5,#categoryList4,#categoryList3,#categoryList2" ).hide();
        $.post( "/trobay/categories/default/lists?parent_id="+$(this).val(), function(data) {
               if(data !=='0'){
                  $( "select#categoryList1" ).show();
                  $( "select#categoryList1" ).html( data );
               }else{
                   $("#categoryList5,#categoryList4,#categoryList3,#categoryList2,#categoryList1" ).hide();
                   $( ".iconSuccess" ).show();
                   $( ".mydiv" ).append($a);
                     alert(1);
                     alert($a);
                 }

               //alert($a);
        });

   });
```

The below image is a screenshot of the message i got back from the server and the green icon only shows up when data return "0"

[image]

I hope this put more light on the question and any help will be apppreciated

Comment: If you don't even see the `alert(1)` then `data != 0` or your AJAX request is failing. Try `data == "0"` and also heck the console for errors. Also note that you're not passing anything to any anonymous function, you're simply setting a variable in its scope. If the AJAX request was successful, what you have would work fine.

Comment: if u dint see the alert(1) something wrong check response data ==0 is the data is string or integer if string u have to change to data == "0"

Comment: Try to put alert into your `else` statement.. and see if the alert runs.. Otherwise, you just fail to parse the `data`.

Comment: The ajax response is working it returns data if it's not equal to 0 and also it $(".iconSuccess").show(); div the first line in the if condition which mean it works perfect when it returns 0

Comment: The else statement return data and display it in a select menu which works a i expected, now i only need to get a variable value $a = $("#categoryList option:selected").text(); and display this in if statement which is not working